# Swift - Google AdMob Randomly stopped working

Tags: ios, admob

I setup Google AdMob in my app and it worked when I was testing. Then I published to the store and sure enough the ads appeared after 24 hours. But I recently updated my app with minor improvements and the ads stopped appearing. I don't know why.

When I run the app now, it logs:

```
2022-03-10 11:43:26.065651-0600 Aquan[8433:2763115] <Google> To get test ads on this device, set: 
Objective-C
    GADMobileAds.sharedInstance.requestConfiguration.testDeviceIdentifiers = @[ @"SECRET" ];
Swift
    GADMobileAds.sharedInstance().requestConfiguration.testDeviceIdentifiers = [ @"SECRET" ]
2022-03-10 11:43:26.065815-0600 Aquan[8433:2763115] <Google> Note that test device identifiers may be reset when uninstalling and reinstalling the application.
2022-03-10 11:43:26.070957-0600 Aquan[8433:2763159]  - <Google>[I-ACS025031] AdMob App ID changed. Original, new: (nil), "SECRET KEY"
2022-03-10 11:43:26.150777-0600 Aquan[8433:2763159]  - <Google>[I-ACS023007] Analytics v.80901000 started
2022-03-10 11:43:26.150985-0600 Aquan[8433:2763159]  - <Google>[I-ACS023008] To enable debug logging set the following application argument: -APMAnalyticsDebugEnabled (see )
2022-03-10 11:43:26.201406-0600 Aquan[8433:2763162]  - <Google>[I-ACS800023] No pending snapshot to activate. SDK name: app_measurement
2022-03-10 11:43:26.322826-0600 Aquan[8433:2763160]  - <Google>[I-ACS023012] Analytics collection enabled
true
2022-03-10 11:43:26.674003-0600 Aquan[8433:2763153] <Google> Cannot find an ad network adapter with the name(s): com.google.DummyAdapter. Remember to link all required ad network adapters and SDKs, and set -ObjC in the 'Other Linker Flags' setting of your build target.
2022-03-10 11:43:27.275638-0600 Aquan[8433:2763115] [Error] Failed to load cached image from gamed: monogram-128@2x~iphone.gkpix
cache key: avatars__G:444967191monogram-128@2x~iphone.gkpix
2022-03-10 11:43:31.434205-0600 Aquan[8433:2763115] [Error] Failed to load cached image from gamed: monogram-128@2x~iphone.gkpix
cache key: avatars__G:444967191monogram-128@2x~iphone.gkpix
```

Has anyone else had this problem?

Comment: set -ObjC in the 'Other Linker Flags' setting of your build target. Is this truned ON?

Comment: also check your app readiness status https://support.google.com/admob/answer/10564477?hl=en&ref_topic=7384409

Comment: @AmodGokhale thank you. My app meets all the readiness status' and -ObjC is enabled in other linker flags